# How to set the text in one select based on the selection in another select

Tags: javascript, jquery

The HTML on the first button is not important.  When I set its value, it launches this function:

```
function selectCustomer(str) {
c = str;
$("select.btn btn-primary options").text("All");
}
```

I want this function to change the text of the following `select` to "All", instead of its default, "Filter".

```
<select class="btn btn-primary options">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Filter</option>                                                       
  <option>All</option>
  <?php                              
  foreach ($outputEnd as $name=> $o) {

    print "<option class=\"dis\" value=\"\" disabled>$name</option>";

    foreach ($o as $p) {          
      print "<option>$p</option>";
    }
  }                                

  ?>                                     
  </select>
```

How would I go about this?

This code, `$("select.btn btn-primary options").text("All");`, is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is a little off. Also, you should use `val` off the `select` element:

```
$("select.btn.btn-primary.options").val("All");
```

Your code is selecting `select.btn btn-primary options` which would actually look something like this:

```
<select class="btn">
  <btn-primary>
     <options></options>
  </btn-primary>
</select>
```

Which does not make much sense :)

Comment: this will change every button which uses the class `"select.btn.btn-primary` though... I make distinctions between the classes using "select.btn.btn-primary options" and "select.btn.btn-primary names" and "select.btn.btn-primary etc..."

Comment: It does though - I'm utilizing multiple classes with this button.  `btn` , `btn-primary`, and `options` are all separate items in my `.css` file.  So it loads different pieces of css based on what's in each.  Your code DOES work - it just changes the value of ALL my buttons to `All` instead of just this one button.

Comment: Ah, I see, you want "options" to be used as a class. I'll make an edit.

Comment: The edit will target a `<select>` element with classes of "btn", "btn-primary" and "options".

Comment: ahh - so the `.` in between each word is what makes it "drop down to the next class I've listed".  Perfect.  Thank you so much!  This way I can use `$("select.btn.btn-primary.options")` and `$("select.btn.btn-primary.names")` and `$("select.btn.btn-primary.blahblahblah")`

Comment: Please note that you need to remove the spaces from the selector and keep correct syntax: ".btn options" is not the same as ".btn.options".

Comment: Correct. jQuery uses `document.querySelector`'s syntax, which is essentially css.

Answer (score 0):

To set an input's value you need the `val` method, so: `$("select.btn").val("All");`

Note that you need to add this to the select item not its options.